# Recommended location for Java applications on iseries

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I have a Java application, which I will be calling remotely using CommandCall.

At present I have placed it in `/home/username` folder, and specify this folder in the CLASSPATH parm of JAVA command.

But now I have to ship the application to clients, and it seems these are the possible locations

- Creating directory in root, like `/myapp`
- Creating directory in QOpenSys, like `/QOpenSys/myapp`. This was roughly mentioned in [this ITJungle article](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg032206-story02.html)

But I have not found mention of recommended location in the iSeries documentation.

So whats the recommended location to deploy Java application on iSeries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for IFS path organization.

I prefer to deploy to a path such as `/opt/<application>` or `/opt/<vendor>/<application>`.  I also create environment directories such as `test`, `dev`, `prod`, etc within that structure.

Note that `/opt` is located on a case-insensitive filesystem.  If that is an issue you could also use `/QOpenSys/opt`.

I would suggest not creating any new root directories.

Comment: I don't have /opt folder - neither in root, nor in /QOpenSys --- does that I simply create one ?

Comment: @vikramsjn If it's a standard directory, such as `/opt`, yes.